# Tab switch event available for Google Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

As a Google Chrome extension, is it possible to listen to tab switches? That is, to be notified when a tab switch has just happened?

(I want to make an extension that, in fullscreen, when switching tabs with the usual <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd> keyboard shortcuts, gives visual feedback of the switch and other currently available tabs.)

Comment: Look at this link: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html (see available Events)

Answer (score 21):

In your manifest.json file add the following:

```
"permissions":[
    "background",
    "tabs"
],

"background" : {
    "scripts": ["scripts/background.js"],
    "persistent": false
}
```

In your background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
    console.log(activeInfo.tabId);
});
```

Comment: Does this also work if the tab you're switching to is in a different window?

Answer (score 14):

It's possible, see [`onActivated`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#event-onActivated) at https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#event-onActivated

Answer (score 2):

note: tab url may not be available when using `chrome.tabs.onActivated` so use  [chrome.tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#event-onUpdated) instead.