# Javascript "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I call my script when `changeInfo.status=== 'complete'` from the background section in a chrome plugin. I want to check if the title has 65 in it, but I'm getting an error. how can i solve this problem?

```js
if(document.querySelector(".title").textContent.search(65))
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null
```

Comment: `document.querySelector(".title")` is returning a null value which means its not found

Comment: `search` doesn’t make sense in an `if` statement like this. You want [`test`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) instead. Or simply [`includes`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about `title` tag? if yes, acess the `title` directly from `document` like this:

```
document.title.search(65)
```

Comment: no im not talking about title tag there is class title btw if i refresh page my code is work but  when switching between pages, the page does not refresh, my code does not work then.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233866/tab-switch-event-available-for-google-chrome-extension
You need to handle a tab switch event and then call the querySelector code